# How to track events from a parent widget

Tags: python, pyqt5, popupwindow, mouseleave

My goal is that when I hover my mouse over the thumbnail image, a popup image of the original image will display to the right of the mouse; and if my mouse leaves the thumbnail, the popup destroys itself.

The issue I have is that the `leaveEvent` from the thumbnail does not trigger, because the popup takes control of the application main loop (or that is what I think is happening - I am not actually sure).

Here is my code:

```
class UI_ImagePopup(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        QLabel.__init__(self)
        movie = QMovie("C:/Users/Zelly/Desktop/thumbnail/1vgb1al.jpg", QByteArray(), self)
        movie_screen = QLabel()
        # Make label fit the gif
        movie_screen.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        movie_screen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        # Create the layout
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(movie_screen)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        # center the zoomed image on the thumb
        position = self.cursor().pos()
        position.setX(position.x() +50)
        position.setY(position.y())
        self.move(position)
        # The following is blackmagic copy pasted from the internet
        # FramelessWindowHint may not work on some window managers on Linux
        # so I force also the flag X11BypassWindowManagerHint
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Popup | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint 
                            | Qt.FramelessWindowHint 
                            | Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint)
        movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
        movie.setSpeed(100)
        movie_screen.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.close()

class Ui_ImageLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        QLabel.__init__(self)
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap("C:/Users/Zelly/Desktop/thumbnail/1vgb1al.jpg"))
        self.p = None

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        print("Enter event")
        self.p = UI_ImagePopup()
        self.p.show()
        event.accept()

    def leaveEvent(self, event): # not triggered
        print("Leave event")
        self.p.destroy()

class Ui_MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(1024, 512) #TODO: Resizable
        self.setMaximumSize(1024, 800)
        self.gridlayout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.gridlayout)
        for i in range(6):
            pic = Ui_ImageLabel()
            self.gridlayout.addWidget(pic,0,i)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys_argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    sys_exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: **WARNING**: I have added a mouse handler to the example so that clicking on the popup will close it. Without this, the example is quite dangerous, because it can grab all mouse and keyboard events.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve by setting those window flags. Why is it necessary to force the window manager to give total control to the popup?

Comment: A result of troubleshooting the popup displaying with a windows border. I had worked off of [this](http://www.intransitione.com/blog/pyqt-playground-image-gallery-with-zoom/). Is this my issue? I will look more into these flags.

Comment: Getting rid of the `Qt.Popup` flag will probably solve your problem (assuming it works the same way on all platforms). (PS: you should also use `close()` rather than `destroy()`.

Comment: Yeah it appears removing the Popup flag prevents the event locking, however it then brings up a window in the taskbar every time the popup is active, which is to be honest I can work with. I assume I would need to approach doing the popup differently if I wanted to avoid that. Also thank you I had noticed the destroy was making the app not close properly.

Comment: In that case, try `Qt.Tool` instead of `Qt.Popup`. This works for me on linux, but I cannot test on other platforms.

Comment: That does seem to fix it with no visible side effects at the moment, thank you!